# Alien doomsday movie where a good and bad alien fight whilst two kids look for a doomsday device

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, soft-sci-fi

There are two kids and two aliens in this alien doomsday movie, one good and one bad. I believe the "good" alien is Dwayne Johnson or Vin Diesel. The "bad" alien is of  size and shape of the ones in the beginning of *The Fifth Element*, they throw  chakra like weapons. The two aliens battle it out, while the two kids look for some hidden doomsday device. Which is hidden beneath a silo thing in a barn.

Comment: Have you tried going through the filmography on imdb for those two actors?

Comment: It would help if you mention when you saw the movie and if it was new at the time. Other details could also help, even if they seem insignificant to you. For instance, were the kids a boy and a girl or two boys?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be *[Race to Witch Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_to_Witch_Mountain)*? It features Dwayne Johnson, not as an alien, but rather as a cab driver who meets two teenagers — the aliens — who are pursued by an alien bounty hunter.